Possible Reasons For Azure Cache for Redis Occasionally Not Returning All Data When Query
As the title states, sometimes when the front end of our application sends a query to the backend the cache does not return all of the data it normally would by quite a large amount.
If the cache is flushed, then all of the data is returned the next time it is queried for.
Likewise, if the cache is disabled and the query goes straight to the database all of the data is returned.
What could be the possible causes of this behaviour?
The set up is as follows: GraphQL API <-> Azure Cache for Redis <-> Azure SQL

Doing a RCA without any data will be difficult, there are many cause such as . Stale or Incomplete Data in the Cache, Fragmentation or Sharding Issues, Concurrency and Write-Read Race Conditions, High Cache Turnover or Capacity Issues, Network Latency or Connection Issues, Serialization/Deserialization Issues, Issues with Data Expiry Policies. Need more details on your environment to deduce the root cause. For now please refer to these docs-

https://bobcares.com/blog/data-loss-in-azure-cache-for-redis/#:~:text=At%20times%2C%20most%20or%20all%20keys%20disappears%20from,Redis%20instance%20failure%3A%20The%20Redis%20server%20is%20unavailable.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-troubleshoot-data-loss
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-troubleshoot-timeouts
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-troubleshoot-server.md
